# Is it possible to connect to MongoDB Atlas using the legacy C++ API (version 1.1.2)?

Tags: c++, mongodb

I'm trying to connect to MongoDB 4.2.3 in MongoDB Atlas using the legacy *(and no-longer supported)* C++ API 1.1.2, and seeing errors like:

> component [NETWORK ], context []: connected to server cluster0-shard-00-02-zbydr.mongodb.net:27017 (52.48.177.64)
>
> component [NETWORK ], context []: No primary detected for set Cluster0-shard-0
>
> component [NETWORK ], context []: All nodes for set Cluster0-shard-0 are down. This has happened for 33 checks in a row. Polling will stop after -3 more failed checks
>
> Connection failed - connect failed to replica set Cluster0-shard-0/cluster0-shard-00-00-zbydr.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-01-zbydr.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-02-zbydr.mongodb.net:27017

I can connect through the shell and from Node.js without problems - so the issue is either that my connection string is in the wrong format or simply that the legacy C++ API can't connect to MongoDB 4.2 / Atlas. I am using the following connection string:

```
mongodb://username:password@cluster0-shard-00-00-zbydr.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-01-zbydr.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-02-zbydr.mongodb.net:27017/database?replicaSet=Cluster0-shard-0&authSource=admin
```

Am I correct in concluding that the legacy C++ API can't connect to a MongoDB 4.2 **cluster**? (I have tested connecting directly to a single instance of MongoDB 4.2, and that appeared to work fine.) Perhaps Atlas itself requires functionality only supported by the newer APIs?

Comment: Atlas requires TLS/SSL, try adding that option to your connection string

Comment: Also, the legacy driver had some nonstandard ways of specifying connection info, if I remember correctly. You may just need tor read the code or step through with a debugger to figure out where it is failing. As you note, the legacy driver is no longer supported.